# What is common between the words?

Tags: word, pattern

What is common between the following words and names?

- Sweden
- Ashton Kutcher
- salmon
- dogs
- Emma stone
- Germany
- elk
- Chicago
- Miami
- Margot Robbie
- heart transplant
- countryside

Comment: Can we have a hint?

Comment: They all use the alphabet.

Comment: Words without Q.  I think we need a hint. ; )

Answer (score 1):

This might be a huge stretch, but is it:

> Jimmy Kimmel?

Sweden

> [Alicia Vikander Celebrates Sweden's Midsummer Holiday with Jimmy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXeVp6aNwwY)

Ashton Kutcher

> Ashton played a [voice swap game on The Tonight Show](https://www.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/celebrities/2020/05/05/mila-kunis-ashton-kutcher-cant-stop-laughing-jimmy-fallon-video/3084866001/)

salmon

> Clips of the bit have been removed, but [a forum post](https://forums.footballguys.com/topic/436565-jimmy-kimmel-tests-out-new-trick-or-treats/?do=findComment&comment=9465714) quotes a bit where Jimmy Kimmel pitches the cereal "Honey Bunches of Salmon"

dogs

> This one is a little less direct, but from [his Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Kimmel) (emphasis mine), "Kimmel has performed in several animated films, often voicing **dogs**. His voice appeared in Garfield: The Movie and Road Trip, and he portrayed Death's Dog in the Family Guy episode "Mr. Saturday Knight..." He also has (at least one) [dog](https://www.today.com/popculture/watch-jimmy-fallon-s-dog-gary-crash-his-monologue-t180959)

Emma stone

> In his Oscars speech in 2018, [he took a shot at Emma Stone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVxoDtWK2Mk)

Germany

> From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Kimmel), "two of his paternal great-great-grandparents were German immigrants", and he is [quoted](https://laist.com/2017/08/15/jimmy_kimmel_charlottesville.php) as saying "Germany is taking a stronger stance on Nazis than we are."

elk

> His [bucket list adventure](https://robbreport.com/lifestyle/sports-leisure/inside-jimmy-kimmels-robb-report-bucket-list-adventure-montana-230496/) consists of eating elk

Chicago/Miami

> He is present on news sites/networks in [Chicago](https://www.nbcchicago.com/tag/jimmy-kimmel/) and [Miami](https://miami.cbslocal.com/tag/jimmy-kimmel/), although these seem less solid

Margot Robbie

> Margot has [appeared on the show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEEkXCCgz2o) multiple times

heart transplant

> While it's not a transplant, [his son has gone through heart surgery](https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/parenting/2019/09/18/jimmy-kimmel-spider-man-son-billy-thriving-2-years-post-heart-surgery/2362684001/)

countryside

> Some of his interviews have [involved the countryside](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xz4ZBUrZhUo&lc=Uggz8K_SMPSFSXgCoAEC)? That's all I've got for this one

If this isn't it, I think we're gonna need a hint :D