# With a little effort, one can prevail

Tags: wordplay, pattern, lateral-thinking, no-computers, english

What is common between the following words and names?
(Inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105339/what-is-common-between-the-words) except that I actually know the answer to this one)

- Defeat
- Kleenex?
- Guanaco
- Nerdiest
- Sardar
- Ian McKellen
- Dingo
- Gun
- Diablo
- Essayed?
- Atlanta
- Glycose
- Get
- Earns
- Group
- Desmid
- Terraculture

The answer is self-confirming.

Hint:

> Does it seem like these words have nothing in common? Does it seem like attempting this puzzle will result in failure?
>  I may not be asking quite what you think I am asking.  The tags and hints in the post will guide you.  : )

Hint:

> The answer is non-trivial. For example, 'Unallowed' cannot be added to this list even though it has a capital, has a hyphen/bullet, is a word, etc.

Comment: All the words described have their vowels numbered as a prime (I am considering 1 as a prime) but Ian Mckellen is not working. Also, those question marks -- do they mean anything? Like are you asking whether it satisfies the condition or not? [Originally posted as an answer because user hadn't enough rep to comment -- The Mgmt]

Comment: rot13(gurl'er nyy jbeqf va gur dhrfgvba?) hahaha I very much doubt that's the correct answer, interested in seeing what people come up with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we may successfully

> insert **win** between each pair of words to find a word formed from neighbouring letters.

The list is:

> Defeat - twinkle - Kleenex
>  Kleenex? - X-wing - Guanaco (question mark as a proper name and a hyphen)
>  Guanaco - cowinner - Nerdiest
>  Nerdiest - twins - Sardar
>  Sardar - Darwinian  - Ian McKellen
>  Ian McKellen - enwinding - Dingo
>  Dingo - owing - Gun
>  Gun - unwind - Diablo
>  Diablo - blowiness - Essayed
>  Essayed? - Edwina - Atlanta (question mark as a proper name)
>  Atlanta - awing - Glycose
>  Glycose - sewing - Get
>  Get - twine - Earns
>  Earns - swing - Group
>  Group - upwind - Desmid
>  Desmid - midwinter - Terraculture
>  Per the hint, I don't think any word can end in 'win' and a prefix of 'unallowed'.

Comment: Excellent work finding what is common *between* the words!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the [lateral-thinking] tag is there, so

> if we take "between" rather literally, there are *bullet points* between all the pairs of words, so those are "common between" them. (The hint *does* say "I may not be asking quite what you think I am asking".)

Comment: Great guess and you are in the right mindset. Could be correct except it is not self-confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is

> the Font?

That would explain why there are question marks, as

> the words are replaceable with every sign or letter in that font.
> My problem is the "english" tag. The language would be irrelevant - but there is a font called "effort" like mentioned in the title so maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: No, the English language is important for seeing the solution.