# Commonality between this contiguous list of words?

Tags: word, pattern, word-property

Whilst walking home from a long shopping trip, my friend sent me a text, which read:

> Hey, Brainiac! I remember that time you won 4 spelling bee's in a row, so here's something to scratch your brain with. Try and find out what these words have in common:
>
> • Havana
>
> • Antidisestablishmentarianism
>
> • Megalomaniac
>
> • Crabapple
>
> • Everlasting
>
> • Grandfather
>
> • Rockaway
>
> • Yemen
>
> • Neonatology
>
> • Yarrow
>
> • Warrior
>
> • Realistic
>
> • Calisthenics

I texted my friend the answer in a pretty short time, using the hints he threw at me, and disregarding the curveballs. Can *you* figure it out?

(P.S.: I got the idea for this [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105339/what-is-common-between-the-words), though these are different puzzle types. Have fun.)

Comment: Ah, didn't know if it went further than that. Updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited to go with my first guess....

> Each share the same common letter between their end and the start of the next word

This matches the title hint 'contiguous'